# angular directive link function not firing in ie8

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, internet-explorer-8

I have a simple directive that doesn't work in IE8.  Works in all other browsers. I was able to get other directives to work in IE8 by using attributes instead of elements (i.e. Restrict 'A' in the directive).  This one still doesn't.  Not sure what may be the issue.  Any ideas?

My html:

```
<div notificationloader notification="vm.notification" 
  notification-empty-message="empty message">
</div>
```

My js:

```
   (function () {

        'use strict';

        angular.module("bellApp").directive('notificationloader', ['$http', 'notificationService', notificationLoaderDirective]);

        function notificationLoaderDirective($http, notificationService) {
            return {
                restrict: "EA",
                scope: {
                    notification: "=",
                    notificationEmptyMessage: "@"
                },
                link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                    scope.notification = scope.notificationEmptyMessage;
                    notificationService.checkIfNotificationAvailable(setNotification);

                    function setNotification(response) {
                        if (response != undefined && response.data.trim().length > 0) {
                            scope.notificationAvailable = true;
                            scope.notification = response.data;
                        }

                    };
                }
            };
        }
    })();
```

Comment: Is there any error in console..?

Comment: I think in IE8 you need to prefix attributes with `data-`. Could be wrong about that but it's worth a shot. Angular will automatically ignore `data-` prefix on attributes.

Comment: I had a conditional comment hiding the directive in ie8.  Man!!!